Hanging kitchen cabinets on drywall with asbestos joint compound
I'm working on renovating our kitchen and getting ready to install our cabinets.
The current backsplash will need to go and I would more than likely need to screw the new cabinetry into sections of "hot" drywall mud.
Should I call in the professionals to remove the drywall or is there a safe DIY route forward? Any and all help is appreciated!

The cabinets are screwed through the  drywall into the studs. You need to find and mark the studs. Then drill through the correct part of the cabinet to hit the studs .How do you know the drywall joint compound has asbestos?

I'd think, unless you're pulling the drywall down and grinding it up, you should be OK. As long as the compound stays intact there's miniscule danger from any asbestos.

When was your house built?

@Huesmann It was built in ~1970

@RMDman Some time ago I had another section of drywall/joint compound tested for asbestos and it was "hot"
